# Is there any difference about thread safety strategy between accessing member directly and accessing by self.name?

Tags: ios, thread-safety, accessor

I have the code below. 
I'm wondering that does the `self.value` and `_value` have some difference about thread safety strategy?

```
//temp.h
@interface Temp:NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSInteger *value;

@end

//temp.m
@implementation Temp

@synthesize value = _value;

- (void)someMethod:(NSInteger)someValue {
    self.value = someValue;
}

- (void)someOtherMethod:(NSObject *)someValue {
    _value = someValue;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are exactly the same in terms of what you asked.  Thread safety is not affected (it would be if you used atomic instead of nonatomic though, IIRC).